# Can PDMS silicone be produced with dichloromethane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, polymers, organosilicon-compounds

I was taking a simulated admission test for a Technology Institute (Brazilian ITA) and one of the questions asked for the production of PDMS silicone via these described steps:

1. Reaction of $\ce{SiO2}$ with carbon, freeing $\ce{CO2}.$
2. Non-volatile product of (1) reacting with dichloromethane in a $\ce{H2}$-rich atmosphere.
3. Product of (2) reacting with water giving PDMS and $\ce{HCl}.$

The proposed solution was:

$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{align}
\ce{SiO2 + C &-> Si + CO2}\tag{1}\\
\ce{Si + 2 CH2Cl2 + 2 H2 &-> Si(CH3)2Cl2 + 2HCl}\tag{2}\\
\ce{n Si(CH3)2Cl2 + n H2O &-> \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\;(}OSi(CH3)2\enclose{horizontalstrike}{)_n} + 2n HCl}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

However, this route does not follow the Rochow process (direct process) with chloromethane on step number 2. This created confusion among the students who took the test because it was hard to know if this route even existed and that $\ce{HCl}$ had to be dispensed on step number 2 to balance the equation.(Weird to come up with this by yourself.)

The question that remained among the confusion is:

Can PDMS be produced via this dichloromethane route?

Haven't found any information directly related to this on the internet.